# Getting item from database returns only en version

Tags: sql-server, sitecore8

I'm trying to get an item from database then publish it via code. The item only has `pt-pt` language (portugal)

I'm using `Database.GetDatabase`, when I try to get the item from the database. It gives me an item that has `en` language.

```
Item item = Database.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(guid);
```

Then when I try to edit the item using `Editing.BeginEdit()`, it edits the `en` version then proceeds to publish it.

Is there a way to get the `pt-PT` version then edit that version instead of en?

Answer (score 0):

Each item can contain multiple languages. You can use the `Sitecore.Globalization.Language` class to specify a language when accessing an item using the `Sitecore.Data.Database.GetItem()` method. For example, to access the current version of the `/Sitecore/Content/Home` item in the default `en` language:

```
Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

Sitecore.Globalization.Language language = Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse("en");

Sitecore.Data.Items.Item home = master.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home",language);
Note
```

If you do not specify a language, Sitecore uses the context language by default. Sitecore user interface components specify the content language.

You can use the `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.Versions.Count` property to determine if any versions exist for a language. For example, to access the current version in each language of the /`Sitecore/Content/Home` item in the Master database:

```
Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

Sitecore.Data.Items.Item home = master.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");

foreach (Sitecore.Globalization.Language language in home.Languages)
{
    Sitecore.Data.Items.Item langItem = home.Database.GetItem(home.ID, language);
    
    if (langItem.Versions.Count > 0)
    {
        // Process language item
    }
}
```